# Getting error while using Appium for login

Tags: appium, appium-android

Can someone please help me. I am new to Appium, I have an Android App that I am trying to Automate.

I have written a code for invoking the App and from there I want to login. 
But I am unable to login getting the below error:

```
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"Login ID","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"Login ID","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'Login ID' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.navistar.writeup:id/Login ID]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/Login ID]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=Login ID]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=Login ID, INSTANCE=0]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'Login ID' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.navistar.writeup:id/Login ID]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/Login ID]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=Login ID]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=Login ID, INSTANCE=0]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
```

Comment: Please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) properly.

Comment: Those are just the logs.

Comment: Are you trying to automate a web app?  The locator is attempting to locate using resource-id which means it thinks it's accessing a native app.  If the app is a browser and you're accessing a web page, you'll have to change the context and locate elements that way.

Comment: My App that I am automating is a combination of Native and Web App. With the code that I have written I am able to open the App using UIautomator I am able to locate elements as well. After running the code App opens up but It's unable to take user name and password.

Comment: I only happened upon your response just now.  I recommend that you use xpath since it appears you are indeed trying to locate "Login ID" as an HTML ID and not a resource-id.  When you attempt to locate by ID using native methods, as you can see, it automatically tries to look for resource-id but it's not finding it, possibly because it's not a resource ID, but an HTML ID tag on a web page?  What exactly are you using as a locator, or what method?  Show some code so I can better help you.  You might want to tag my name so I can see your response, too.

Comment: Bill Hileman - I couldn't add my code. Is there any way I can send you logs and code?